# Do I need to sort after Group by, before an Merge Join

Tags: kettle

I need to GroupBy and MergeJoin in PDI (Kettle). Both are made ​​using the same field as the key.

I could not find anywhere to confirm that after the GroupBy data remains ordered.

In case I need to know if it would be correct: 
SORT> GROUPBY> SORT> MERGEJOIN 
or 
SORT> GROUPBY> MERGEJOIN

Someone could tell me what the correct and why?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort BEFORE the Group By and the Merge Join based on the keys you're grouping or joining on. The data on exit will have the same order as before, so if you group and then merge based on the same keys, you don't need the sort between Group by and Merge Join.

If the keys change, however, you do.